# Help of using "late" in a sentence

Tags: sentence

Is it correct that I say to my teacher "would you please start the class 30 minute late?" if I want to ask him to change the time of class from 16:00 to 16:30. 
and what do native people say?

Comment: Depending on level of formality and familiarity with the teacher, I’d probably say, “Could we start at 4:30 on Monday because <reason>” or “Monday’s lesson plan is very interesting to me and I really don’t want to miss any of it. But I’ve got to do <something> and won’t be able to make it to class until 4:30.  I was just wondering whether it would be possible to start class at 4:30 on Monday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say "Could you start the class at 16:30 instead of 16:00?" The class is on time if it starts at the agreed upon time, so it's not "late" if you both agree to start at 16:30. "later than usual" also applies if 16:00 is the usual time. If the class could be scheduled to start at many different times, then there is no "usual" time, so "later than usual" would be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I would say *"Could you please start the class 30 minutes later than usual?"* or *"Would you mind starting the class 30 minutes later than usual?"*

I must say that it's an odd request to make of a teacher, and it might tend to get the response "No - why don't you just make sure you turn up on time?"

Comment: Yes; this seems a strange one. 'The lesson started 5 minutes late' is perfectly acceptable, but 'Will you start the lesson 5 minutes late, please' sounds much less idiomatic.